# Challenge : Encriptador de Texto usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo finalizado el código de un challenge llamado "Encriptador de Texto" con 3 botones: encriptar, desencriptar y copiar.

El problema es que no ejecuta algunas condiciones y funciones mi JS por ejemplo, encripta el texto pero no lo desencripta (debe mostrarlo desencriptado).

Esto es porque desaparece el texto al dar click en `DESENCRIPTAR` y por lo tanto, no puedo copiarlo tampoco porque se esfuma el texto.

Y tampoco cumple con la condición de no tolerar caracteres especiales.

El código que usé es el siguiente:

**Variables (Almacenamiento Información)**

**Captura y almacena el texto que ingresa en el encriptador**

```
const textArea = document.querySelector(".text-area");
```

**Captura y almacena el texto encriptado**

```
const mensaje = document.querySelector(".mensaje");
const copia = document.querySelector(".copiar");
copia.style.display = "none"
```

**VALIDAR TEXTO**

```
function validarTexto(){
    let textoEscrito = document.querySelector(".text-area").value;
    let validador = textoEscrito.match('/^[a-z]+$/i');

    if(!validador || validador === 0) {
        alert("Solo son permitidas letras minúsculas y sin acentos")
        location.reload();
        return true;
    }
}

function btnEncriptar(){
    if(!validarTexto()) {
        const textoEncriptado = encriptar(textArea.value)
        mensaje.value = textoEncriptado
        mensaje.style.backgroundImage = "none"
        textArea.value = "";
        copia.style.display = "block"
    
    }
}
```

**// La letra "e" es convertida para "enter"//**
**// La letra "i" es convertida para "imes"//**
**// La letra "a" es convertida para "ai"//**
**// La letra "o" es convertida para "ober"//**
**// La letra "u" es convertida para "ufat"//**

**función botón**

```
function btnEncriptar() {
    const textoEncriptado = encriptar(textArea.value)
    mensaje.value = textoEncriptado
    textArea.value = "";
    mensaje.computedStyleMap.backgroundImage = none;
    
}
```

**String para recibir el dato**

```
function encriptar(stringEncriptada) {
    let matrizCodigo = [["e", "enter"], ["i", "imes"], ["a", "ai"], ["o", "ober"], ["u", "ufat"]];
    let newStringEncriptada = stringEncriptada
    newStringEncriptada = newStringEncriptada.toLowerCase();
```

**Bucle de recorrido**

```
    for (let i = 0; i < matrizCodigo.length; i++) {

        **//condición para verificar array y letras//**
    

if (stringEncriptada.includes(matrizCodigo[i][0])) {

            **//sustituciones de letras//**

        newStringEncriptada = stringEncriptada.replaceAll(matrizCodigo[i][0], matrizCodigo[i][1])
    }
}
return newStringEncriptada
```

}

**DESENCRIPTAR**

```
function btnDesencriptar(){
    const textoEncriptado = desencriptar(textArea.value)
    mensaje.value = textoEncriptado
    textArea.value = "";
    
}


function desencriptar(stringDesencriptada){
    let matrizCodigo = [["e", "enter"], ["i", "imes"], ["a", "ai"], ["o", "ober"], ["u", "ufat"]];
    let newStringDesencriptada = stringDesencriptada
    newStringDesencriptada = newStringDesencriptada.toLowerCase()

    for(let i = 0; i < matrizCodigo.length; i++){
        if(stringDesencriptada.includes(matrizCodigo[i][1])){
            newStringDesencriptada = newStringDesencriptada.replaceAll(matrizCodigo[i][1] , matrizCodigo[i][0])

        }

    }
    return stringDesencriptada
}
```

**COPIAR**

```
function copiar(){
    mensaje.select();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(mensaje.value)
    mensaje.value = "";
    alert("Texto Copiado")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Criptografía

La criptografía es un campo complejo que está ligado estrechamente con las matemáticas y requiere conocimientos técnicos avanzados y recursos computacionales significativos. Lo que entiendo de tu ejemplo es que intentas *"encriptar"* una cadena, sin embargo no sigues ningún estándar de seguridad, por lo que tu método no puede considerarse como tal "encriptar" sino convertir texto a un pseudo-idioma, para cifrar datos de forma segura normalmente se usan algoritmos de cifrado fuerte como *AES* o *CBC*.

Aún así, aquí tienes una modificación con las pautas que mencionas.

- La letra *"a"* es convertida para *"ai"*
- La letra *"e"* es convertida a *"enter"*
- La letra *"i"* es convertida a *"imes"*
- La letra *"o"* es convertida para *"ober"*
- La letra *"u"* es convertida para *"ufat"*
- ...

(Recuerda que puedes ajustar esto según tus necesidades)

```js
const letters = {
  "a": "ai",
  "b": "be",
  "c": "ce",
  "d": "de",
  "e": "enter",
  "f": "efe",
  "g": "je",
  "h": "ache",
  "i": "imes",
  "k": "ka",
  "l": "ele",
  "m": "eme",
  "n": "ene",
  "ñ": "eñe",
  "o": "ober",
  "u": "ufat",
  "p": "pe",
  "q": "qu",
  "r": "erre",
  "s": "ese",
  "t": "te",
  "u": "ue",
  "v": "ube",
  "x": "equis",
  "y": "ye",
  "z": "seta",
  " ": "espacio",
  ".": "punto"
  // aqui agrega los caracteres adicionales que necesites
}

function encriptarTexto(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string") return "no es un string";
  const parts = [...str];
  // o bien puedes usar: const parts = str.split("");
  const final = [];
  for (const val of parts) {
    const crypt = letters[val.toLowerCase()];
    if (crypt) {
      // determinar mayus
      if (val.toUpperCase() === val) {
        // es mayus
        final.push(crypt+"__mayus");
      } else {
        final.push(crypt);
      }
    } else {
      // no existe, maneja el error
    }
  }
  return final.join(" ");
}

function desencriptarTexto(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string") return "no es un string";
  const final = [];
  const parts = str.split(" ");
  for (const part of parts) {
    const raw_letters = Object.entries(letters);
    const letter = raw_letters.filter(e => e[1] === part.replace("__mayus", ""))[0];
    if (letter) {
      // determinar mayus
      if (part.endsWith("__mayus")) {
        final.push(letter[0].toUpperCase());
      } else {
        final.push(letter[0]);
      }
    } else {
      // no existe, maneja el error
    }
  }
  return final.join("");
}

const crypted = encriptarTexto("El valiente gato maullaba feliz por la noche.");
const decrypted = desencriptarTexto(crypted);

console.log(crypted);
console.log(decrypted);
```

En este código, he seguido procesos de validación y conversión que te detallaré a continuación:

1. **Comprobación de entrada**: En todas las funciones, determinamos primero si la entrada es un string, de lo contrario, devolveremos una cadena que diga *"no es un string"*.

El truco está aquí:

```js
if (typeof str !== "string") return "no es un string";
```

Este código usa [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para recuperar el tipo nativo de un dato, si no coincide con `string`, que dicho de paso, es el tipo de dato esperado, la función se deniega a ejecutar con un `return`.

2. **Segmentación de la cadena**: En este caso, he usado la [**Sintaxis Spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para separar el texto por cada dígito, de esta manera podremos manejar mejor la conversión. Aquí convertiremos el `string` a un `array`. Ejemplo:

```js
[..."Hola mundo"] // ["H", "o", "l", "a", " ", "m", "u", "n", "d", "o"]
```

Que equivale a:

```js
"Hola mundo".split(""); // ["H", "o", "l", "a", " ", "m", "u", "n", "d", "o"]
```

3. **Conversión a caracteres conocidos**: Al principio, listamos un objeto llamado `letters`, en él especifico todas las letras que se pueden esperar y sus respectivos equivalentes *"codificados"*, esto nos servirá para recuperar la información que necesitamos.
4. **Recuperar la información**: Para recuperar la información en el proceso de conversión de texto plano al pseudo-idioma, usamos un ciclo `for` que nos sirve para iterar cada letra de la cadena que recibimos, para asegurarnos que no haya falla, convertimos la cadena a minúsculas con [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), ya que nuestro objeto, el cual contiene la información de las letras y sus entidades en clave, tiene las letras en minúsculas, además que te puede ahorrar tiempo al no tener que poner todas las letras en minúscula y mayúscula. Luego obtendremos la entidad codificada con un código relativamente simple

```js
const crypt = letters[val.toLowerCase()];
```

Aquí definimos una constante la cual tendrá por valor la entidad codificada. Lo que hacemos es convertir la letra que estamos iterando a minúscula usando el método [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) y recuperarlo desde el objeto.

5. **Comprobación de existencia**: Si la letra no existe dentro de nuestro objeto que actúa como diccionario, no se hace nada, pero puedes cambiar esto. Concretamente esto sucede en este extracto

```js
if (crypt) {
    ...
} else {
  // no existe, maneja el error
}
```

Puedes cambiar este código por lo que te parezca conveniente para manejar un error, pero ten en cuenta que si arrojas un error o pones un `return`, todo el demás código dejará de ejecutarse.

6. **Comprobación de mayúsculas**: Si la letra que estamos iterando es mayúscula, esto podría afectar la calidad del texto cuando se desencripte, porque recuerda que en nuestro objeto diccionario, tenemos letras únicamente minúsculas. Hay muchas formas de manejar esto, pero la que yo he visto más simple y conveniente es convertir la letra a mayúscula y compararla cona la letra que estamos iterando, para esto estoy usando el método [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase). Si la letra resulta ser mayúscula, pondremos el texto codificado, seguido de `__mayus`, de esta manera podremos identificar letras mayúsculas al momento de desencriptar.
7. **Devolución de la cadena encriptada**: Devolvemos la cadena encriptada en un array que definimos antes, la cadena está separada en cada código por espacios, para que podamos interpretarla. Para hacer esto usamos el método [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

El proceso de desencriptar el texto es relativamente parecido. Sin embargo aún así, es importante que te detalle el proceso.

1. **Comprobación de entrada**: En todas las funciones, determinamos primero si la entrada es un string, de lo contrario, devolveremos una cadena que diga *"no es un string"*.

El truco está aquí:

```js
if (typeof str !== "string") return "no es un string";
```

Este código usa [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para recuperar el tipo nativo de un dato, si no coincide con `string`, que dicho de paso, es el tipo de dato esperado, la función se deniega a ejecutar con un `return`.

2. **Segmentar la entrada**: Como antes separamos el texto de salida en espacios, ahora haremos el proceso inverso, es decir: separar el texto por cada espacio. Para esto, he usado el método [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Ejemplo

```js
const str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

const words = str.split(' ');
console.log(words[3]);
// Expected output: "fox"

const chars = str.split('');
console.log(chars[8]);
// Expected output: "k"

const strCopy = str.split();
console.log(strCopy);
// Expected output: Array ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."]
```

(Extraído de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)).

Esto nos va a servir para poder iterar cada elemento y poder determinar la letra correspondiente a cada código.

3. **Obtener las letras**: Primero obtendremos las letras para encontrar el código correspondiente a cada una de ellas, para obtener las letras que son las llaves del objeto, usaremos el método [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Ejemplo

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 };
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]

// array like object
var obj = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // [ ['0', 'a'], ['1', 'b'], ['2', 'c'] ]

// array like object with random key ordering
var an_obj = { 100: 'a', 2: 'b', 7: 'c' };
console.log(Object.entries(an_obj)); // [ ['2', 'b'], ['7', 'c'], ['100', 'a'] ]

// getFoo is property which isn't enumerable
var my_obj = Object.create({}, { getFoo: { value: function() { return this.foo; } } });
my_obj.foo = 'bar';
console.log(Object.entries(my_obj)); // [ ['foo', 'bar'] ]

// non-object argument will be coerced to an object
console.log(Object.entries('foo')); // [ ['0', 'f'], ['1', 'o'], ['2', 'o'] ]

// iterate through key-value gracefully
var obj = {a: 5, b: 7, c: 9};
for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + value); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
}

// Or, using array extras
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key + ' ' + value); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
});
```

(Extraído de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)).

4. **Obtener la letra correspondiente al código**: Para obtener la letra correspondiente al código, usaremos el método [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), para filtrar las letras y obtener la letra correspondiente al código. Este extracto funciona así

```js
const letter = raw_letters.filter(e => e[1] === part.replace("__mayus", ""))[0];
```

Lo que hacemos es definir una constante y filtrar las letras, por cada una de ellas, obtendremos el valor del objeto del principio, como puede que incluya `__mayus`, usaremos el método [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para reemplazar `__mayus` del string, y que no haya problemas al momento de obtener la letra correspondiente.

5. **Comprobación de existencia**: Si el código no existe dentro de nuestro objeto que actúa como diccionario, no se hace nada, pero puedes cambiar esto. Concretamente esto sucede en este extracto

```js
if (letter) {
    ...
} else {
  // no existe, maneja el error
}
```

Puedes cambiar este código por lo que te parezca conveniente para manejar un error, pero ten en cuenta que si arrojas un error o pones un `return`, todo el demás código dejará de ejecutarse.

6. **Comprobación de mayúsculas**: Como antes definimos una regla, de que si la letra es mayúscula, el código termine en `__mayus`, ahora podemos manejar esto, si el código termina en mayúsculas, convertiremos la letra que recuperamos a mayúsculas, para comprobar si un `string` termina con otro específicamente, podemos usar el método [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), y luego [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) para convertir la letra a mayúscula

---

### Consideraciones

- Ten en cuenta que *"encriptar"* de esta manera del lado del cliente y sin un cifrado fuerte, corresponde a un problema crítico de seguridad, para producción, es mejor usar algoritmos de cifrado fuertes como *AES* o *CBC*.
- Además, usar métodos *"caseros"* como este, estará extremadamente limitado, por ejemplo, este código solo encriptará cadenas con los idiomas que contengan las letras que tiene el objeto, si no los contiene, no será posible la encriptación, los métodos de cifrado que mencioné abordarán de manera automática estos aspectos.
- Aún con un algoritmo de cifrado fuerte, es extremadamente importante mantener los estándares de seguridad. Esto puede incluir: guardar claves secretas en un lugar seguro, proteger y filtrar las entradas del cliente, entre otros.

---

### Enlaces de interés y referencias

- [Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
- [Block cipher mode of operation (CBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [Sintaxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)
- [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 1):

```js
   

const textArea = document.querySelector( ".text-area" );
const mensaje = document.querySelector( ".mensaje" );
const copia = document.querySelector( ".copiar" );
const enc = document.querySelector( ".btn-encriptar" );
const des = document.querySelector( ".btn-desencriptar" );
enc.addEventListener( "click", btnEncriptar );
des.addEventListener( "click", btnDesencriptar );
copia.addEventListener( "click", copiar );  

// saque la matriz de las funciones, para no repetir código
let matrizCodigo = [[ "e", "enter" ], [ "i", "imes" ], [ "a", "ai" ], [ "o", "ober" ], [ "u", "ufat" ]];

function validarTexto() {
  let textoEscrito = document.querySelector( ".text-area" ).value;
  let validador = textoEscrito.match( '/^[a-z]+$/i' );
  
    // cambié el regex porque no funcionaba
  validador = textoEscrito.match( '[a-z]' );

  if( ! validador || validador === 0 ) {
      alert( "Solo son permitidas letras minúsculas y sin acentos" );
      location.reload();
      return true;
  }
}

// eliminé esta función porque estaba repetida... o casi
//function btnEncriptar2() {
//    const textoEncriptado = encriptar( textArea.value )
//    mensaje.value = textoEncriptado
//    textArea.value = "";
//    //mensaje.computedStyleMap.backgroundImage = "none";    
//}

function btnEncriptar() {
  if( ! validarTexto() ) {
      const textoEncriptado = encriptar( textArea.value );
      mensaje.value = textoEncriptado
      mensaje.style.backgroundImage = "none"
      textArea.value = "";
      copia.style.display = "block"    
  }
}

// esta función recibe una cadena sin encriptar, cambiamos
// "stringEncriptada" por "textoParaEncriptar"
function encriptar( textoParaEncriptar ) {  
  // let newStringEncriptada = textoParaEncriptar
  // newStringEncriptada = newStringEncriptada.toLowerCase();
     // reemplazo las dos lineas por:
  let newStringEncriptada = textoParaEncriptar.toLowerCase();   
  for( let i = 0; i < matrizCodigo.length; i++ ) {
      if( newStringEncriptada.includes( matrizCodigo[i][0] )) {
          newStringEncriptada = newStringEncriptada.replaceAll( matrizCodigo[i][0], matrizCodigo[i][1] );
      }
  }
  return newStringEncriptada
}

function btnDesencriptar(){  
     // acá tenemos la situación inversa, asignas el texto desencriptado a una variable llamada "textoEncriptado"
  // const textoEncriptado = desencriptar( textArea.value )
  const textoOriginal = desencriptar( textArea.value );
  mensaje.value = textoOriginal;
  textArea.value = "";    
}

 // y van 3!! recibimos un texto encriptado
// function desencriptar( stringDesencriptada ) { 
function desencriptar( stringEncriptada ) { 
  // let newStringDesencriptada = stringDesencriptada;
  // newStringDesencriptada = newStringDesencriptada.toLowerCase();
     // aplicamos la misma simplificación
  let newStringDesencriptada  = stringEncriptada.toLowerCase();
  for( let i = 0; i < matrizCodigo.length; i++ ) {
      if( newStringDesencriptada.includes( matrizCodigo[i][1] )) {
          newStringDesencriptada = newStringDesencriptada.replaceAll( matrizCodigo[i][1] , matrizCodigo[i][0] );
      }
  }
  return newStringDesencriptada;
}

function copiar(){
  mensaje.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(mensaje.value)
  mensaje.value = "";
  alert("Texto Copiado")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<title>Encriptador </title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="/imagenes/Logo.png" alt="logo de alura">
</header>
<main>
    <section>
        <!-- INGRESO DE TEXTO -->
        <textarea class="text-area" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ingrese el texto aqui"></textarea>
        <div>
            <h6 class="informacion">Por favor, ingrese sólo letras minúsculas y sin acentos</h6>
        </div>
        <!-- BOTONES -->
        <div class="botones">
            <button class="btn-encriptar">Encriptar</button>
            <button class="btn-desencriptar">Desencriptar</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- TEXTO INGRESADO ENCRIPTADO-->
    <section>
        <textarea class="mensaje" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div>
            <button class="copiar">Copiar</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

El lado bueno,
la lógica del programa está bien, puede parecer poco, pero no lo es, si te recomiendo prestar especial atención a los nombres.
PD: como ejercicio, está más que bien, ahora, para encriptar, no es válido, debes encriptar letra por letra, para no tener situaciones "extrañas", por ejemplo, si introduzco "e enter", cuando encripte, obtendré "enter enter" y cuando desencripte, "e e", osea un funcionamiento errático.

Edición: justamente el ejemplo que dí, no genera ese comportamiento errático... cosas de la lógica, que se me quiere escapar.

Comment: Gracias por responder y darte el tiempo de edición y nueva implementación del código 
Te comento que intenté con -copiar y pegar- sólo el código que me entregaste y no me funcionó. No encripta; el texto queda igual en la caja de ingresar el texto.

Comment: Coloqué el código dentro de los snippets, para que puedas ver que funciona, supongo que el problema está en los nombres de los elementos de tu html, recuerda que no lo veo, y me inventé las cosas, si puedes subir tu html, podemos ver en que lugar se produce el error.

Comment: Cierto, tienes mucha razón! 
Acabo de subir mi HTML como respuesta en comentario a mi publicación :)
Repito: Muchísimas gracias por estar ayudándome, soy nueva en esto ^^

Comment: realicé unos cambios en mi código y en el HTML quité los **onclick** ya que es mala práctica, debes acostumbrarte a separar, HTML, CSS, y JS, cada uno en su propio archivo, se hace más fácil entender, se hace más fácil mantener, elimina tu respuesta, así evitarás votos negativos!!